# python basic authentication check

Tags: python, http, authentication

I'm trying to make script that check for the web page if it requires a basic http authentication or not before executing the needed command .

I'm sorry but i don't understand the libraries and the commands related to this check at python , I tried to search for it but failed to find any useful info .

For example I need the script to check the page www.google.com if it is gonna ask for credentials to view the page or not then complete the command.

Comment: Anything missing from the answer to make you un-accept a year later? :-)

Answer (score 3):

If a server expects the client to use basic authentication, it'll respond to a request *without* such authentication with a `WWW-Authenticate` header, containing the word `'Basic'`. See the [Basic Authentication Scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1) section of the HTTP RFC.

Using the standard Python libraries, you can test for that with:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError

try:
    response = urlopen(url)
except HTTPError as exc:
    # A 401 unauthorized will raise an exception
    response = exc
auth = response.info().getheader('WWW-Authenticate')
if auth and auth.lower().startswith('basic'):
    print "Requesting {} requires basic authentication".format(url)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd'
>>> try:
...     response = urlopen(url)
... except HTTPError as exc:
...     # A 401 unauthorized will raise an exception
...     response = exc
... 
>>> auth = response.info().getheader('WWW-Authenticate')
>>> if auth and auth.lower().startswith('basic'):
...     print "Requesting {} requires basic authentication".format(url)
... 
Requesting http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd requires basic authentication
```

To add a timeout to the request as well, use:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, HTTPError
import socket


response = None

try:
    response = urlopen(url, timeout=15)
except HTTPError as exc:
    # A 401 unauthorized will raise an exception
    response = exc
except socket.timeout:
    print "Request timed out"

auth = response and response.info().getheader('WWW-Authenticate')
if auth and auth.lower().startswith('basic'):
    print "Requesting {} requires basic authentication".format(url)
```

Comment: Thanks, dude it worked , but could you explain where i can add a timeout for the code ?

Comment: @abualameer94: Use `urlopen(url, timeout=15)` for a timeout of 15 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn . I added the timeout and it worked perfectly but when the url exceed the time limit it shows it as and error how i can add an exception for the timeout issue .?

Comment: @abualameer94: the timeout throws a `socket.timeout` exception; you'll have to import that and handle it separately.

Comment: Hello, After editing the code to the code you gave me I faced this error , It's a strange one . the previous one was working perfectly and now both is not working ..

Comment: @abualameer94: that error has nothing to do with my code; your network connection doesn't work, not for those hosts. That's a routing error or similar, nothing to do with the code posted here.

Comment: @abualameer94: I've rolled back the edit you made to the question because it's nothing to do with Python, I am afraid. You could perhaps ask for help on this on SuperUser.com, provided you include network setup details and what address you are trying to reach.